# PHP :taking sub strings from given string

Tags: php, regex, string

I have string in the following format.

Option1:Option2:Option3:Option4

I want to get these items separated and put it into a array.

> array(item1=>option1,item2=>option2,item3=>option3,item4=>option4)

etc.

is there a straight forward way to get this done using regular expressions with PHP.

Thanks in advance for sharing your experience with me.

Comment: read about function `explode()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: [`explode`](http://www.php.net/explode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$arr = explode(":", $string);` and then do this:

```
$result = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i ++) {
    $result['item' . $i] = $arr[$i];
}
```

and you should find `$result` to be exactly what you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use explode function for that

```
$array = explode(":", $str);
```